# lastname and firstname initials in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex

Is there a fast way to automatically show lastname and then initials in the bibliography/References list? I use biblatex package with natbib and authoryear style. F.ex, the author is listed as Peter Nielsen but should be Nielsen, P.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mylib.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The option `giveninits` lets you switch to given name initials instead of full given names.

With `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` you can change the order of names to "Family, Given" (i.e. "Last, First").

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, giveninits]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. and Ryde, U. (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]