# RNA journal reference format

Tags: biblatex

This is taken from RNA journal (https://rnajournal.cshlp.org/site/misc/ifora_msprep.xhtml).

**Citations.**

For single authors, cite as (name date) in text; citations are not numbered. For citations with two authors, cite as (surname and surname date). For citations with more than two authors, do not list all authors. Cite as (first author's surname et al. date) in text. Undated citations (unpublished, in preparation, personal communication) should include first initials and last names of all authors up to three before et al.--e.g., (F Smith, pers. comm.)--and do not appear in the reference list.

**Below is the mwe in LaTeX. I am not able to get the above format.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{apaauthor}{first-last}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames{labelname}%
    \iffieldundef{year}
      {}
      {\nameyeardelim\printdate}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\title{\textbf{Title}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
My single line \cite{sampath2004noncanonical, stöhr2006zbp1, lees1979evaluating, tymowska1991polyploidy, raimondi2023landscape}. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**this is ref.bib file**

```
@article{sampath2004noncanonical,
  title={Noncanonical function of glutamyl-prolyl-tRNA synthetase: gene-specific silencing of translation},
  author={Sampath, Prabha and Mazumder, Barsanjit and Seshadri, Vasudevan and Gerber, Carri A and Chavatte, Laurent and Kinter, Michael and Ting, Shu M and Dignam, J David and Kim, Sunghoon and Driscoll, Donna M and others},
  journal={Cell},
  volume={119},
  number={2},
  pages={195--208},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{stöhr2006zbp1,
  title={ZBP1 regulates mRNA stability during cellular stress},
  author={Stöhr, Nadine and Lederer, Marcell and Reinke, Claudia and Meyer, Sylke and Hatzfeld, Mechthild and Singer, Robert H and Hüttelmaier, Stefan},
  journal={The Journal of cell biology},
  volume={175},
  number={4},
  pages={527--534},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Rockefeller University Press}
}

@article{lees1979evaluating,
  title={Evaluating student writing},
  author={Lees, Elaine O},
  journal={College Composition and Communication},
  volume={30},
  number={4},
  pages={370--374},
  year={1979},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{tymowska1991polyploidy,
  title={Polyploidy and cytogenetic variation in frogs of the genus Xenopus},
  author={Tymowska, Janina},
  journal={Amphibian cytogenetics and evolution},
  volume={259},
  pages={297},
  year={1991},
  publisher={Academic Press San Diego}
}

@article{raimondi2023landscape,
  title={The landscape of cancer rewired GPCR signaling axes},
  author={Raimondi, Francesco and Arora, Chakit and Matic, Marin and Rosa, Natalia De Oliveira and Nemati, Lorenzo and Clubb, Lauren and Kargas, Giorgos and Vukotic, Ranka and Licata, Luana and Wu, Guanming and others},
  journal={bioRxiv},
  pages={2023--03},
  year={2023},
  publisher={Cold Spring Harbor Laboratory}
}
```

**References.(Expected/wanted)**

Only articles that are published, in press, or posted to a preprint server whose papers are fully citable should be included in references. "Et al." should be used ONLY after the first 10 authors. References should be arranged alphabetically by author and not as numbered citations. It is the authors’ responsibility to not cite any retracted article. Please observe the following reference style:

Sampath P, Mazumder B, Seshadri V, Gerber CA, Chavatte L, Kinter M, Ting SM, Dignam JD, Kim S, Driscoll DM, et al. 2004. Noncanonical function of glutamyl-prolyl-tRNA synthetase: gene-specific silencing of translation. Cell 119: 195–208. doi:10.1016/j.cell.2004.09.030

Stohr N, Lederer M, Reinke C, Meyer S, Hatzfeld M, Singer RH, Huttelmaier S. 2006. ZBP1 regulates mRNA stability during cellular stress. J Cell Biol 175: 527–534. doi:10.1083/jcb.200608071

Strunk W, White EB. 1979. The elements of style. Macmillan, New York, NY.

Tymowska J. 1991. Polyploidy and cytogenetic variation in frogs of the genus Xenopus. In Amphibian cytogenetics and evolution (eds. Green DM, Sessions SK), pp. 259–297. Academic Press, San Diego, CA.

For preprint servers: Preprints deposited in bioRxiv, for example, should be cited using their digital object identifier (doi).
Example: Author AN, Author BT. 2013. My article title. bioRxiv doi: 10.1101/123456.

If the paper includes website URLs as references to places where material was obtained for doing the work (with the exception of preprint servers, such as bioRxiv.org, whose papers are fully citable—see details above), the URL should be included next to that information in the text.

**References.(what I get from above code)**

[image]

Comment: According to [this page](https://rnajournal.cshlp.org/site/misc/ifora_acceptance.xhtml) on the journal website, they do not seem to accept `LaTeX` submissions. As a consequence, I would suggest you convert your text to Microsoft Word as suggested by the publisher.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't want to submit here. This is for my thesis. I want this format.

Comment: Fair enough. To make your problem clearer, you should display a precise example showing what is the difference between what you obtain and what you want to have. If the problem is with the year that appears in parenthesis, you could look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/184389). If the problem is with the number of authors in the reference list, you should look at the `maxbibnames` option in [the documentation](https://texlive.mycozy.space/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). If it is something else, please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: question is edited. thx for suggestion.

Comment: To reverse the last name and first name and have only initials for first name, you should look [at this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464740/184389)

Comment: For the abbreviation of journal names, my personal opinion is that it would be more efficient to do it by hand. If you want an automated way, you could look [at this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34764/184389)

Comment: For the `Tymowska` reference, you might not have provided the correct format in your `.bib` file. Look at the `incollection` entry type in [the documentation](https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

Comment: To have capital letters in `article` titles other than the first letter, you should surround them with braces (e.g. `{GPCR}`}

Comment: To have DOIs in your references, you should provide a `doi` field to the reference for which you want it

Comment: And as a general rule, the citations generated by Google Scholar are not trustworthy at all as they often report information incorrectly (wrong type of entry, errors in the names of authors/document/journal, ...)